# Is it possible to change Kalista's bound ally?

Tags: league-of-legends

So my strategy would be to bind with my support during the laning phase, then (why not?) change the bind with a better initiator for team fights. Is it possible to change it, and how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No this is not possible.**

You can only rebind within 3minutes into the game

http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-421-notes#patch-kalista

Comment: Is it free, and can you do it whenever you want? No restriction, no time limit?

Comment: sorry... i was wrong with the first version.

Comment: "Meh I don't want Janna anymore... Let's take Malphite"

Comment: Also I suggest when taking kalista.. try to pair with someone who can initiate, like leona or thresh. That way your ult will be viable up to late game

Comment: you should always bind with your support. the support should be a champion that can initiate

Comment: @Pierre Binding is free and you can do it whenever you want. Highly recommend doing it as soon as the game starts though because it takes a couple seconds to complete.

Comment: @ChaseC he asked about the rebinding

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW I was answering his comment not the question. I thought his comment was in regards to the first time you bind with someone.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can actually...
More into the development into LoL, they've done changes to Kalista. The item that allows her to bound an ally can actually be REUSED 25 minutes into the game. As it helps with team fights, and if a tank that usually goes in is getting very low, you can ult.

Comment: I'm actually really curious where you got this information. It's so... not close to anything i've heard that I would love to see the source.